# Getting the address of a triple pointer to char

Tags: c, pointers

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I am just wondering why I am getting different memory address. When I print the address of animals in main I get the following:

```
animals [ rabbit ] : [ 0xbfab2e48 ]
animals [ rabbit ] : [ 0xbfab2e48 ]
```

However, when I print in the function, I get different memory locations. I think they should be the same.

```
ptr animals [ rabbit ] : [ 0xbfab2e08 ]
ptr animals [ rabbit ] : [ 0xbfab2e08 ]
```

Many thanks for any advice,

```
int main(void)
{
    char *animals[] = {"rabbit", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "racoon", NULL};
    char *countries[] = {"india", "amercia", "france", "spain", "canada", "mexico", NULL};
    char *cars[] = {"ford fista", "Masda 3", "honda city", "toyata cote", NULL};
    char **ptr_data[] = {animals, countries, cars, NULL};

    printf("animals [ %s ] : [ %p ]\n", *animals, (void*)animals);
    printf("animals [ %s ] : [ %p ]\n", animals[0], &animals[0]);

    print_data_ptr(ptr_data);

    return 0;
}

void print_data_ptr(char ***ptr)
{
    char **data_list = NULL;

    printf("ptr animals [ %s ] : [ %p ]\n", *ptr[0], (void*)&ptr[0]);
    printf("ptr animals [ %s ] : [ %p ]\n", **ptr, (void*)ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`animals` is an array of `char *` values, and `ptr_data` is an array of `char **` values.

When you initialise `ptr_data` in this line:

```
char **ptr_data[] = {animals, countries, cars, NULL};
```

`animals` is evaluated as a pointer to its first element - so `ptr_data[0]` is the same as `&animals[0]` - the address of the first `char *` in `animals`.  The same thing happens in your two `printf()` functions in main - `animals` and `&animals[0]` evaluate to the same thing, which is also the pointer value stored in `ptr_data[0]`.

Within your function, `ptr` is a pointer to the first element of `ptr_data` in main - so `ptr` is equivalent to `&ptr_data[0]`.  `&ptr[0]` is completely equivalent to `ptr` - so `&ptr[0]` shows you the address of `ptr_data[0]`, not what is stored there.  If you print `ptr[0]` instead, you will get the address of `animals[0]`.